# How to select React subcomponents in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am writing a SCSS file for my React app which uses React Semantic UI (https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction). How can I get the CSS to select subcomponents? For example an `<Item.Group>` tag.

I can't just write `Item.Group { ... }` because it recognizes the Group as a class, not a subcomponent of Item.

Comment: Using tags named  `<Item.Group>` is a bad idea to start with. Tagnames should be all lower-case and kebab-case.

Comment: I am using React.js where the convention is to use uppercase tags for components. Also `<Item.Group>` comes from the framework (similar to Bootstrap) I linked to in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a `className` to the group you want to style and using this in your SCSS selector.

If you want to style every `Item.Group` in your app, you can inspect the generated HTML to see what classes are set on an item group by default. Looking at the Semantic UI docs, it seems to be `class="ui items"` so the CSS selector would be `.ui.items`

Comment: Ok I was thinking to do it this way but was wondering if there were any more elegant ways.

Comment: @NotAMonkey24 I would consider `.items` elegant. Semantic UI is all about semantic naming convention after all. The `Item.Group` is only the name of the React component. It has no bearing on the HTML elements created (mostly divs) or the classes (which follow the Semantic CSS library names). You could inline the css into your React, but this requires either Higher Order Components or repetition.